# Fiori Manage Bank Accounts not visible on launchpad

Tags: hana, sap-fiori

We are configuring Manage Bank Accounts App in our S/4 Hana 1610 landscape(Front End and BackEnd are on the same Server).
All the App specific Installation pre-requisite's are met.

My queries are :

1. Not able to see Tile for Manage Bank Accounts App in Business Catalog : SAP_SFIN_BC_CM_BAM,Business Group : SAP_SFIN_BCG_CM_BAM although all the respective roles have been assigned.
2. As per Technical Configuration,not able to see LPD_CUST Role : UIAPFI70  and Instance TRANSACTIONAL_CM  in LPD_CUST Transaction.

Please Advice.

Regards,
Rehan Sayed

Comment: Which guideline did you use for installing this app ?Do you get any error messages ? Perhaps the following might be useful to you: [App Implementation: Manage Bank Accounts](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_fiori_sfin_200/helpdata/en/12/5ec0544e238d21e10000000a44176d/content.htm) and [App Implementation: Manage Bank Accounts](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_fiori_sfin_300/helpdata/en/12/5ec0544e238d21e10000000a44176d/content.htm)

Comment: Here are also some resources regarding SAP Fiori Launchpad: [SAP Fiori – SAP Fiori launchpad troubleshooting](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/29/sap-fiori-sap-fiori-launchpad-troubleshooting/), [SAP Fiori LL17 – SAP Fiori launchpad configuration steps](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/06/12/sap-fiori-ll17-sap-fiori-launchpad-configuration-steps/), and [Troubleshooting](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/9e/767a37cbee4d618d866bf4576a1df3/content.htm)

Comment: @SAPFioriCrew Thanks for the reply,we are on S/4 Hana 1610, does this means that we are on S/4 Hana Finance 1610 ?
Please let me know how to check for S/4 Hana Finance version in SAP ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by following sap note 2269272 and below Link.

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw75/helpdata/en/52/2749ec852a4779845ee028e5b950a1/content.htm

Run report /UI2/GET_APP_DESCR_REMOTE in test mode first and then execute.